# Menu System: Custom Links

Tags: menus, links

Is there a way to set default values for options selected in the WordPress menu system? My example would be if the "Custom Link" option was chosen, can this default to a _blank target? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

sure, just click Screen Option on top, and check Link Target and you will have the option on the link to target the same or a different page

Comment: Thanks for the response - to be more clear, I mean changing the default dropdown value of the "Custom Links" "Link Target" only for that menu option. Thanks.